# Programmatically access Manifest.permission?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to gain access to the list of Permissions in [Manifest.permission](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html), which is a final class. How do I gain access to its declared String values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken literally, I believe the question is about how to simply get the list of POSSIBLE permissions, not the runtime permissions on a package.  Assuming that's true, this is simply a reflection question.

You would do something like this (not compiled):

```
List<Field> permissionFields = new ArrayList<Field>();
Field[] fields = Manifest.permission.class.getDeclaredFields();
for (Field declField : fields) {
  if ((declField.getType() == String.class) && Modifier.isFinal(declField.getModifiers())) {
    permissionFields.add(declField);
  }
}
```

The "permissionFields" list holds the list of objects that are permission values.  You can use the "Field.getObject(obj)" method to get the String value (curiously, there doesn't appear to be a "Field.getString(obj)" method, although there are several other "Field.get(obj)" methods (perhaps because String isn't a primitive)).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code:

```
Log.d(TAG, "Getting permissions for " + packageName);
try {
    PackageInfo pkgInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                packageName, 
                PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS
              );
    PermissionInfo[] permissions = pkgInfo.permissions;
    if (permissions == null) {
    permissionsField.setText("No declared permissions");
    }
    else {
    String permissionsText = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++) {
        switch (permissions[i].protectionLevel) {
            case 0:
                permissionsText += permissions[i].name + ":::" + "NORMAL" + "\n";
                break;
            case 1:
                permissionsText += permissions[i].name + ":::" + "DANGEROUS" + "\n";
                break;
            case 2:
                permissionsText += permissions[i].name + ":::" + "SIGNATURE" + "\n";
                break;
            case 3:
                permissionsText += permissions[i].name + ":::" + "SIGNATUREORSYSTEM" + "\n";
                break;  
        }
    }
    permissionsField.setText(permissionsText);
    }

    String[] requestedPermissions = pkgInfo.requestedPermissions;
    if (requestedPermissions == null) {
    requestedPermissionsField.setText("No requested permissions");
    }
    else {
    String reqPermText = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < requestedPermissions.length; i++) {
        reqPermText += requestedPermissions[i] + "\n";
    }
    requestedPermissionsField.setText(reqPermText);
    }
}
catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
    permissionsField.setText("Package Not Found");
    requestedPermissionsField.setText("Package Not Found");
}
```

Comment: please read the question better. This would have been a good response had it been what I was asking for.